# How do I get Mythbuntu to detect my satellite box?

Tags: 12.04, mythbuntu, mythtv, tv-tuner

Background: I have a TechniSat SkyStar USB HD DVB-S2 Digital Satellite USB Box, a fresh install of Mythbuntu 12.04, and I would like Myth to use the satellite box.

My immediate problem is that the kernel doesn't appear to be detecting the satellite box. I installed Kaffeine: it doesn't show any TV devices. The [Kaffeine FAQ](http://kaffeine.kde.org/?q=faq#question20) states that if my device is recognised, there should be DVB messages in `dmesg`; `dmesg | grep -i dvb` doesn't match anything.

[The Technisat SkyStar USB HD is listed as supported since Linux 2.6.39](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/DVB-S2_USB_Devices#Supported_DVB-S2_USB_Devices) on the Linux TV Wiki. `uname -a` says I am running Linux 3.5.0-23-generic.

I don't believe it is a hardware problem, because we got the satellite box working with a Windows 7 PC. I have double-checked that everything is plugged in properly.

How do I get Linux to detect the satellite box?

---

**Edit** (in response to david6's questions):

The final line of output from `lsusb` is

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 14f7:0500 TechniSat Digital GmbH DVB-PC TV Star HD
```

`lsmod | grep -i dvb` and `dmesg | grep -i dvb` both give no output.

---

**Edit** Following the instructions in david6's answer, and after rebooting:

The output of `lsmod | grep -i dvb` is now

```
dvb_usb_technisat_usb2    17976  0 
stv090x                62331  1 dvb_usb_technisat_usb2
dvb_usb                32408  1 dvb_usb_technisat_usb2
dvb_core              105916  2 dvb_usb_technisat_usb2,dvb_usb
rc_core                22172  13 dvb_usb_technisat_usb2,dvb_usb,ir_lirc_codec,ir_mce_kbd_decoder,ir_sanyo_decoder,ir_sony_decoder,ir_jvc_decoder,ir_rc5_decoder,ir_rc6_decoder,ir_nec_decoder,rc_rc6_mce,mceusb
```

The output of `dmesg | grep -i dvb` is now

```
[    2.401826]  79a63c60a6a2ae589e44529401e0ab1150e9408a [media] media: move dvb-usb-v2/cypress_firmware.c to media/common
[    2.732886]  79a63c60a6a2ae589e44529401e0ab1150e9408a [media] media: move dvb-usb-v2/cypress_firmware.c to media/common
[    3.233497] dvb-usb: found a 'Technisat SkyStar USB HD (DVB-S/S2)' in cold state, will try to load a firmware
[    3.234838] dvb-usb: did not find the firmware file. (dvb-usb-SkyStar_USB_HD_FW_v17_63.HEX.fw) Please see linux/Documentation/dvb/ for more details on firmware-problems. (-2)
[    3.234866] usbcore: registered new interface driver dvb_usb_technisat_usb2
```

I still cannot use the satellite box.

I cannot find the `linux/Documentation/dvb/` directory referred to in the `dmesg` output. It is not in the `media_build` repository, and it is not in any Ubuntu package.

Where do I go from here? On the assumption that the `linux/Documentation/dvb/` directory is helpful, where is it?

Comment: **Likely solution is:** Download, compile and install *media_build* (but need more detail on device).

Comment: **Diagnostic steps:** Check output of: **lsusb**, then **lsmod | grep dvb**, and finally **dmesg | grep dvb**.  If no useful output from *lsmod* and *dmesg*, then Ubuntu is not recognising the device.

Comment: @david6 See edit. Is media_build part of Mythbuntu, or do I need to follow [these instructions](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers)?

Answer (score 1):

Device: **14f7:0500**

[Technisat SkyStar USB HD](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/Technisat_SkyStar_USB_HD)

*No, I would not try those instructions: [LinuxTV.org >> How to Obtain, Build and Install V4L-DVB Device Drivers](http://linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/How_to_Obtain,_Build_and_Install_V4L-DVB_Device_Drivers)  No need to over complicate things.*

---

Try what I used: (adapted from: [LinuxTV.org > TerraTec Cinergy T Stick](http://www.linuxtv.org/wiki/index.php/TerraTec_Cinergy_T_Stick))

**NOTE:** *First unplug device, create/install driver, and then plug back in.*

You may need to first install: git, patchutils and Proc::ProcessTable

```
sudo apt-get install git patchutils libproc-processtable-perl
```

Then (to not clutter up root directory)

```
cd ~/Downloads

mkdir drivers
cd drivers

git clone git://linuxtv.org/media_build.git

cd media_build
./build

sudo make install
```

This (download, re-compile, install) may need to be repeated in future, if kernel changes or updates stop device being recognized. This has happened to me twice this year (to date).

*The latest **DVB-Sn** drivers are a work-in-progress.*

---

**UPDATE:** (27-Apr-2013)

This again works, as had been broken for last 15+ days.

Comment: Thank you, this has moved me along, although my problem is not yet solved --- see edit to my question.

Comment: See earlier link ('How to obtain ..'), near end. Section titled: **A Note on Firmware**. *I will investigate further.*

Answer (score 1):

1. download the file [dvb-usb-SkyStar_USB_HD_FW_v17_63.HEX.fw](http://kernellabs.com/firmware/technisat-usb2/dvb-usb-SkyStar_USB_HD_FW_v17_63.HEX.fw)
2. sudo cp your_download_dir/dvb-usb-SkyStar_USB_HD_FW_v17_63.HEX.fw  /lib/firmware/dvb-usb-SkyStar_USB_HD_FW_v17_63.HEX.fw
3. sudo chmod 755 /lib/firmware/dvb-usb-SkyStar_USB_HD_FW_v17_63.HEX.fw

Answer (score 0):

[dvb-usb-SkyStar_USB_HD_FW_v17_63.HEX.fw](http://kernellabs.com/firmware/technisat-usb2/dvb-usb-SkyStar_USB_HD_FW_v17_63.HEX.fw)

the file must be in
/lib/firmware/dvb-usb-SkyStar_USB_HD_FW_v17_63.HEX.fw

in terminal:
chmod 755 dvb-usb-SkyStar_USB_HD_FW_v17_63.HEX.fw

for new kernels like yours 3.5.* no needs to make:
git clone.....

Comment: Please explain your answer. What does one need to do with that file?

Comment: 1.download the file \n 2. sudo cp your_download_dir/dvb-usb-SkyStar_USB_HD_FW_v17_63.HEX.fw /lib/firmware/dvb-usb-SkyStar_USB_HD_FW_v17_63.HEX.fw 3. sudo chmod 755 dvb-usb-SkyStar_USB_HD_FW_v17_63.HEX.fw

Comment: Please update the answer, too. :)